# Haskell Character in String function

Tags: string, list, haskell, character

Hey I'm a pretty new beginner to Haskell and I am having a small problem.

I want to write a function which checks if a given character is in a given string.  Here is my code :

```
inString :: String -> Char -> Bool 
inString [] _ = False 
inString x c = x == c
inString x:xs c = inString xs c
```

For me this makes perfect sense as I know that Strings are just Lists of Characters. But I am getting a `Parse error in pattern : inString`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You have to think in the types for each expresion:

```
inString :: String -> Char -> Bool 
inString [] _ = False 
inString (x::String) (c::Char) = x == c -- won't compile char and strings cannot be compared because they have different type
inString (x:xs) c = inString xs c -- add parenthesis to x:xs -> (x:xs)
```

So a possible way would be:

```
inString :: String -> Char -> Bool 
inString [] _ = False 
inString (x:xs) c = if x == c then True else inString xs c
```

Answer (score 3):

The pattern has to be parenthesized:

```
inString (x:xs) c = inString xs c
```

Comment: (...and there are other problems. But this will get you to the next error.)

Answer (score -1):

You could use the list membership function [elem](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/GHC-List.html#v:elem)

Example:

```
ghci>'c' `elem` "cat" --returns True
```